# Can I make ALIAS for Travis YAML configuration command? ... "travis encrypt GITHUB_TOKEN=****** --add"?

Tags: git, encryption, environment-variables, travis-ci

I have a **Personal Access Token** from Github that I use in many of my projects. Since the token has read/write ability for all my repos, it's important I use the [Travis Command Line Tool](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#readme) to encrypt the `GITHUB_TOKEN`and place it in my `.travis.yml` as a secure variable:

```
travis encrypt GITHUB_TOKEN=****secret**** --add
```

---

## The Problem

- The `GITHUB_TOKEN` value is a hard to remember string of random characters, so every time I need it I first have to go find it, and then copy n' paste it into git bash.
- Whenever I use the `travis encrypt` method, it associates the `GITHUB_TOKEN` with **ONLY** the repository I'm in.

[image]

## Question

Is it possible to make this travis command an alias I can use over and over?

```
[alias]
git repo-encrypt = "travis encrypt GITHUB_TOKEN=****secret**** --add"
```

If so, how and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to add the alias would be to run this one-liner:

```
git config --global alias.repo-encrypt '!travis encrypt GITHUB_TOKEN=****secret**** --add'
```

Alternatively, you can run `git config --global --edit` to open the global Git configuration in your configured text editor (controlled by the core.editor config value of Git). Then add the following to the file:

```
[alias] 
    repo-encrypt = "!travis encrypt GITHUB_TOKEN=****secret**** --add"
```

After you add the alias, running `git repo-encrypt` will execute the Travis command. For future reference, starting a Git alias with a `!` makes it execute the command as though it were a normal shell, instead of simply appending the alias onto the end of the `git` command as it would normally.

See the [Git SCM Book page on aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for more information.

Comment: Also, just in case you need a different level of configuration: `--local` adds the alias to this repository only; `--global` adds the alias to this user's config file; `--system` adds the alias to the Git install-wide config file; `--file <file>` adds the alias to the specified git config file.

Comment: Hi @Emily M, I'm curious if it's possible to customize these alias names to allow for more control? I.E., instead of my `repo-encrypt` command, would it be possible to create an `encrypt:github` command, so that the `encrypt:` could be used with other things I might need to encrypt in the future? I.E. ... `encrypt:twitter` , `encrypt:fb` ,  `encrypt:youtube`, etc... I tried this idea out but it didn't seem to work

Comment: You can do this using bash:
`github(){ echo github;}; twitter(){ echo twitter;}; facebook(){ echo facebook;}; if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]]; then "$1"; else echo "There is no defined function for $1"; fi;` defines a script which executes the first argument as a function if such a function exists. So calling "<script> abc" would execute the function named abc. So define a function for each of the services you want to add a specific command for, and then call the script with the function name as the first argument.

Comment: If you want to avoid using a bash script file you can add the script as a one-line git alias as follows:

`git config --global alias.encrypt-for '!github(){ echo github;}; twitter(){ echo twitter;}; facebook(){ echo facebook;}; if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]]; then "$1"; else echo "There is no defined function for $1"; fi;'`

Then running `git encrypt-for facebook` would run the facebook() function, which would execute and echo "facebook" to the console. Of course you need to add the service-specific code to the functions and replace the echo commands, they are just placeholders.

Comment: The script from earlier is bugged, and the original fix I have deleted because it changed more than actually required to fix the bug. Use `github(){ echo github;};twitter(){ echo twitter;};facebook(){ echo facebook;};if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]];then "$1"; exit 0; else echo "There is no defined function for $1"; exit 1; fi;` instead of the scripts posted above. The change is the addition of two "exit" commands and it applies to both the script file approach and the git alias

Comment: This bugged git alias eventually led to me posting another question, which has now been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41151579/2446574). It explains why the above git alias (`'!github(){ echo github;}; twitter(){ echo twitter;}; facebook(){ echo facebook;}; if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]]; then "$1"; else echo "There is no defined function for $1"; fi;'`) executes twice instead of once.