# Why is this Bash function within a git alias executing twice, and why does adding `exit` fix it?

Tags: git, bash, shell, alias, exit

If I fail to explicitly call [`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/exit.html) for certain function-based Bash scripts then there are additional unexpected executions for some functions. What is causing this? The behavior was first noticed while making a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) as part of answering [another user's question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133801/can-i-make-alias-for-travis-yaml-configuration-command-travis-encrypt-gith/41137150). That alias was composed of this script (*which runs the function twice instead of once*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

github(){
        echo github;            
};

twitter(){ 
        echo twitter;            
};

facebook(){ 
        echo facebook;
};

if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]];
then 
        "$1";
else
        echo "There is no defined function for $1";
fi;
```

But this slightly modified script executes as expected (*runs the function only once*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

github(){
        echo github;            
};

twitter(){ 
        echo twitter;            
};

facebook(){ 
        echo facebook;
};

if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]];
then 
        "$1";
        exit 0;
else
        echo "There is no defined function for $1";
        exit 1;
fi;
```

---

Here is exactly what is happening when I run those scripts via a git alias (*added [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html) command for debugging purposes only*):

```
$ git config --global alias.encrypt-for '!set -evu -o pipefail;github(){ echo github;};twitter(){ echo twitter;};facebook(){ echo facebook;};if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]];then "$1"; exit 0; else echo "There is no defined function for $1"; exit 1; fi;'
$ git encrypt-for "github"
type -t "$1"
github

$ git config --global alias.encrypt-for '!set -evu -o pipefail;github(){ echo github;};twitter(){ echo twitter;};facebook(){ echo facebook;};if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]];then "$1"; else echo "There is no defined function for $1"; fi;'
$ git encrypt-for "github"
type -t "$1"
github
github
```

The output from `set -x`:

```
$ git encrypt-for "github"
++ type -t github
+ [[ function == \f\u\n\c\t\i\o\n ]]
+ github
+ echo github
github
+ github
+ echo github
github
```

The output from replacing `echo github` with `echo "I am echo in github"` as a way of ruling out the `echo` command as the source of the second function execution:

```
$ git encrypt-for "github"
++ type -t github
+ [[ function == \f\u\n\c\t\i\o\n ]]
+ github
+ echo 'I am echo in github'
I am echo in github
+ github
+ echo 'I am echo in github'
I am echo in github
```

---

The following is the simplest version of the alias/script which gives the undesired behavior of double execution:

```
g(){
    echo "once";
};
$1;
```

And this is the resulting output from executing the simplified alias/script (*which has the incorrect behavior of executing twice*):

```
$ git config --global alias.encrypt-for '!g(){ echo "once";};$1;'
$ git encrypt-for g
once
once
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this; it may be something in your environment. Have you tried running this in a clean environment?

Comment: The first script doesn't exhibit the behavior you're claiming. Does your real script contain more code below the `if`/`else`?

Comment: I added an example image of the console output I get when executing the scripts. The added `set` command was only added while I created the image, to help make it more clear what exactly was happening, it isn't present otherwise so I shouldn't be part of the strange behavior.

Comment: A good way to debug your script is to run `bash -x {YOUR_SCRIPT}' and you will see how the script is executed. This will help you understand and debug your issue.

Comment: @JohnKugelman no the entirety of the script is shown.

Comment: And I don't think the example using a git alias is the problem either, this happened when I wrote the script out in a .sh file as well and executed it directly.

Comment: Can you change `set -v` to `set -x`?

Comment: Can you test with simplifications? Try  `git config --global alias.encrypt-for '!g(){ echo github;};g;'` and add parts until it breaks. Perhaps some old alias or function is out there, try renaming your functions into `em_github`.

Comment: @WalterA I have added the simplest version of the script that still displays the problem to the question via an edit. I verified that there is no interference from Bash functions by using `type -t g`. I also verified my git aliases by running `git config --get-regexp '^(alias){1}([.]){1}(.)+'` to list all aliases and the commands they run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because of the way `git` handles aliases:

Given an alias

```
[alias]
    myalias = !string
```

where `string` is any string that represents some code, when calling `git myalias args` where `args` is a (possibly empty) list of arguments, `git` will execute:

```
    sh -c 'string "$@"' 'string' args
```

For example:

```
[alias]
    banana = !echo "$1,$2,SNIP "
```

and calling

```
git banana one 'two two' three
```

`git` will execute:

```
sh -c 'echo "$1,$2,SNIP " "$@"' 'echo "$1,$2,SNIP "' one 'two two' three
```

and so the output will be:

```
one,two two,SNIP one two two three
```

In your case,

```
[alias]
    encrypt-for = "!g(){ echo \"once\";};$1;"
```

and calling

```
git encrypt-for g
```

`git` will execute:

```
sh -c 'g(){ echo "once";};$1;"$@"' 'g(){ echo "once";};$1;' g
```

For clarity, let me rewrite this in an equivalent form:

```
sh -c 'g(){ echo "once";};$1;"$@"' - g
```

I only replaced the `'g(){ echo "once";};$1;'` part (that will be `sh`'s `$0`'s positional parameter and will not play any role here) by a dummy argument `-`. It should be clear that it's like executing:

```
g(){ echo "once";};g;g
```

so you'll see:

```
once
once
```

To remedy this: *don't use parameters!* just use:

```
[alias]
    encrypt-for = "!g(){ echo "once";};"
```

Now, if you really want to use parameters, make sure that the trailing parameters given are not executed at all. One possibility is to add a trailing comment character like so:

```
[alias]
    encrypt-for = "!g(){ echo "once";};$1 #"
```

For your full example, a cleaner way could also be to wrap everything in a function:

```
[alias]
    encrypt-for = "!main() {\
        case $1 in \
            (github) echo github;; \
            (twitter) echo twitter;; \
            (facebook) echo facebook;; \
            (*) echo >&2 \"error, unknown $1"\; exit 1;; \
        esac \
    }; main"
```

---

Hopefully you understood what `git` is doing under the hood with aliases! it really appends `"$@"` to the alias string and calls `sh -c` with this string and the given arguments.

Comment: So, simply removing the $1 at the end of my alias script would give me the desired behavior- if a defined function is specified execute it otherwise error, and it would also not cause double execution. So the alias should be `!g(){ echo "once";};`? If that is correct I will test it and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: @EmilyMabrey: yes, that should work. Now for your actual example, don't overlook my suggestion of wrapping it all in a function (that function can call other functions, of course).

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer! Thanks for your help! I had actually figured out that a "$@" was being added to the end of the script, but I had no idea where it was coming from. My original question mentioned this stray and unexplained "$@" suffix, but upon the criticism of other people (they seemed to think I was mistakenly misinterpreting things) I removed it. It is interesting to see my original instincts about what might be causing the problem were right, but I still wouldn't have gotten much farther without help, so thank you :)

Comment: I will award the bounty sometime later, as currently I can't award it for at least 19 more hours.

Comment: @EmilyMabrey: no problem, glad it helped! (and hopefully will help some other people in the future too!). I looked at the question edit history, and indeed, your original title was about understanding why `"$@"` gets executed… go figure why some downvoted and flagged for close!

Comment: I added an answer containing the edit I originally made to my question since adding an answer to my question seemed against the rules/wrong. You will be getting the bounty no matter what though, so please don't worry about my answer interfering somehow. Thanks so much for you help! (If you celebrate Christmas, I hope you have a merry Christmas!)

Comment: I awarded the bounty! Merry Christmas Eve!

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been answered by [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) so I have created a version of the simplified alias/script which works as I originally intended. Since this is technically an answer and not really part of the question, I have added this as an answer. This answer supplements the other answer by [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) and is not intended to take credit away from his correct answer.

This fixed version of the simplified script either executes a found function or outputs nothing at all, and the fact that Git is placing `$@` at the end of the script is corrected for by the addition of a comment at the end of the script. This is a fixed version of the simplified script (*which gives the correct execution behavior of executing once*):

```
g(){
    echo "once";
};

if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]];
then
$1;
fi;
#
```

Here is the output from this corrected version of the simplified alias/script (*which has the correct behavior: execute once and display nothing for unknown input*):

```
$git config --global alias.encrypt-for '!g(){ echo "once";};if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]];then $1; fi;#'
$ git encrypt-for g
once
$ git encrypt-for github
$ git encrypt-for facebook
$ exit
```

The bottom line is that because of the way Git handles aliases (see [gniourf_gniourf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41305925/2446574) answer for an explanation of that) you must workaround the fact `$@` will be suffixed to the end of your alias/script.